# What happens to weight when ice melts?

Tags: phase-transition, density, weight, matter, density-of-states

A block of ice is weighed in a container. Then, it is left out to melt. Would the weight of the water be greater, less than, or equal to the ice?
I know that it has something to do with density and volume, but i'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internal energy if water is 80 calories per gram higher than that of ice, which represents a finite but incredibly small mass increase, as is clear from Einstein's relation E=mc$^2$. Otherwise the mass is constant. The weight depends also on the gravitational field, which you can assume to be constant over the volume of ice and water. All considered the weight should be the same to a very high accuracy.